# Incomplete subsets of the free boolean algebra on countably many generators

Tags: boolean-algebras

I know that it is provable that the free boolean algebra on countably many generators is incomplete. For the sake of concreteness, let's call the generators $p_1, p_2, p_3,...$ and refer to them as "basic formulas". I have been looking for a concrete example of a subset which lacks either a least upper bound or a greatest lower bound. In fact, I almost gave up; I've been trying to do this for months.

However, I stumbled upon this page: http://thue.stanford.edu/bool.html

The author claims that in the free boolean algebra on countably many generators (FBACMG), "any set $X$ of variables has a least upper bound if and only if the set is finite."

This seems wrong to me: consider the set of basic formulas. If I am not mistaken, it has no upper bounds except the tautology, and thus the tautology must be its least upper bound.

Am I wrong, or is the site wrong? And if the site is wrong, is it possible to describe a subset of the FBACMG which provably has no least upper bound or no greatest lower bound? If not can I prove that it is impossible to describe such a set?

Comment: Stone duality might be helpful to see it more clearly. The free boolean algebra on countably many generators is isomorphic to the algebra of clopens of the Cantor set. A family of clopens has a glb iff there is a least clopen containing the intersection of the family. Now for example clearly there is no smallest clopen neighborhood of a point. (This can be then translated back into an algebraic example if desired.)

Comment: I am inexperienced in topology as I studied boolean algebra in a non-traditional manner (in a mathematical linguistics research seminar). I know some of the advanced theorems (prime ideal theorem, etc) but do not know many other facts you might consider basic. So I am going to try and bring myself to a point where I can understand your comment, @მამუკა. One thing that would help, if you don't mind, is an example of a family of clopens in the cantor set which has a glb.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I actually hadn't seen your comment and dwymark's response before writing my answer. Maybe I should write an addendum that translates the topology back into syntax?

Comment: @ToddTrimble I would really appreciate that and would be happy to accept your answer after doing so. Edit: I'm enjoying learning some basic topology as well. But the translation back into "propositional logic" style formulas should make it immediately understandable for me.

Comment: Actually the statement in my first comment is not correct (the mistake is in the words "containing the intersection of the family"). I will leave it however as it seems to be a characteristic pitfall.

Comment: Your phrase, "Boolean algebra on countably many generators" is not really precise enough, since there are many different Boolean algebras generated by a countable set of their elements. Gaifman proved (years ago) that there are arbitrarily large such algebras, which we now know in forcing as $\text{Coll}(\omega,\theta)$. What you want is the *free* Boolean algebra on countably many generators, and this is also the algebra referred to in the post to which you link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page is mistaken and you are right in your example: if $F$ is an element of the free Boolean algebra on the set $\{p_1, p_2, \ldots\}$ and $p_i \leq F$ for all $i$, then surely $1 \leq F$. One concrete way to think about this is by appeal to Stone duality: the free Boolean algebra is realized concretely as the Boolean algebra consisting of clopen subsets of Cantor space $C = 2^{\mathbb{N}}$. The variable $p_i$ corresponds to the clopen $C_i$ consisting of all points whose $i$-th coordinate is $1$. If some clopen $F$ contains all these $C_i$, then $F$ must be the entire space since the ordinary set-theoretic union of all those $C_i$, which is the complement of the singleton $\{(0, 0, 0,\ldots)\}$, is dense in $C$.

However, similar topological considerations show that this Boolean algebra is not complete. Consider Cantor space $C$ as a subspace of $[0, 1]$ consisting of real numbers between $0$ and $1$ whose ternary expansions have only $0, 2$ as digits. Now any open set in Cantor space is a (countable) union of basic open sets which are finite intersections $C_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap C_{i_n}$. Say we take the open $U$ given by the interval $(.020202..., .202020...) \cap C$, and suppose there were a smallest clopen $F$ containing this. Then, being closed, it would contain the set $[.020202..., .202020...] \cap C$. But being open, $F$ would have to contain all points of $C$ within some $\epsilon$ of $.020202...$. Clearly then you could find a smaller clopen inside $F$ (use $\epsilon/2$ instead), and we reach a contradiction. So the collection of basic clopens we use to form $U$ as a union could have no least upper bound in the Boolean algebra.

**Edit:** I will slightly modify the "$U$" construction above and work instead with the open set $V = (.020202..., 1 = .222222...]$, where again we realize Cantor space $C$ as the subspace of $[0, 1]$ consisting of numbers which in base-3 expansion $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{3^i}$ have $a_i = 0$ or $a_i = 2$ for all $i$. The key point to remember is that the clopen (closed and open) set consisting of all elements of $C$ that (in base 3) start as $.a_1 a_2 \ldots a_n$ corresponds to a conjunction of literals $\lambda_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \lambda_n$ where $\lambda_i = p_i$ if $a_i = 2$ and $\lambda_i = \neg p_i$ if $a_i = 0$. For example, $p_1$ corresponds to the clopen $[.2, 1] \cap C$, and $\neg p_1 \wedge p_2$ to $[.02, .022222... = .1] \cap C$.

Thus, if I am not mistaken, the open set $V = (.020202\ldots, 1]$ is the union of intervals corresponding to the sequence of conjunctions

$$F_1 = p_1,$$ 
$$F_2 = \neg p_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge p_3,$$ 
$$F_3 = \neg p_1 \wedge p_2 \wedge \neg p_3 \wedge p_4 \wedge p_5,$$ $$\ldots,$$ $$F_{n+1} = (\bigwedge_{i=1}^{2n} \neg^i(p_i)) \wedge p_{2n+1},$$ 
$$\ldots$$

and the claim is that there is no least upper bound of this sequence. The topological argument translates into saying that any finite Boolean formula $F$ which dominates all these (in the usual order of the Boolean algebra) must also dominate some formula of the form $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{2n} \neg^i(p_i)$, but then we can slip in yet another dominating formula $F' < F$ by taking the union of $F_1, \ldots, F_{n+1}$ plus $\bigwedge_{i=1}^{2n+2} \neg^i(p_i)$. So there is no least upper bound $F$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am inexperienced in topology as I studied boolean algebra in a non-traditional manner (in a mathematical linguistics research seminar), so I can only get the gist of the argument at this point. It's encouragement for me to learn some topology!
Here is my question: is it possible for me to translate an example like your "U" construction back into the language of equivalence classes of propositional variables? I ultimately aim to use the free boolean algebra in that form for research and knowing which subsets have no glb/lub will help me.

Comment: @dwymark Okay, I added an explanation in more syntactic language.

Comment: Thank you! The "translation" gives me exactly the kind of set I was looking for. The whole answer is extremely helpful and I am enjoying studying it and looking into the relevant topology. Would it be possible for you to give a quick justification for the correspondence between the clopen sets and the conjunctions of literals?

Comment: @dwymark Great! Glad it was helpful. Because these 600-character comment boxes are a little awkward to work with, it could be handy to set up a chat room to discuss this in more detail, and if you'd like, I can set this up later. The background theory is "Stone duality", for which a good set of notes is Halmos's Lectures on Boolean Algebras, and a quickfire online reference is Terry Tao's blogpost https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/245b-notes-1-the-stone-and-loomis-sikorski-representation-theorems-optional/. (continued)

Comment: The original idea of Stone duality is that every Boolean algebra can be concretely represented as a Boolean algebra of (certain) subsets with the usual Boolean operations on subsets. Marshall Stone discovered that the way to do this was set up a topological space nowadays called the Stone space of a Boolean algebra. If $B$ is the Boolean algebra, then the points of the space Stone($B$) correspond to Boolean algebra homomorphisms $B \to 2$ into the standard 2-element Boolean algebra. If $B$ is the free Boolean algebra Bool($p_1, p_2, \ldots$), then such maps $B \to 2$ are uniquely (continued)

Comment: determined by where they send they send the generators $p_i$. Thus for each homomorphism $\phi: B \to 2$ and each $p_i$, there is a value $\phi(p_i) \in \{0, 1\}$, and these $\phi(p_i)$ collectively determine a point with coordinates $(\phi(p_1), \phi(p_2), \phi(p_3), \ldots)$ in the corresponding Stone space. My answer began with the infinite product $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ to indicate this Stone space, but then I quickly switched to the more concrete description as "Cantor space" (continued)

Comment: where a point with coordinates $(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, \ldots)$ in $2^\mathbb{N}$ is more concretely pictured as the point $.200222002\ldots$ (in base 3) in the standard unit interval $[0, 1]$. (Technically we need to use this base-3 trick because that way we get an accurate picture of the topological structure of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.) Now the way Stone duality works, elements $F$ of the Boolean algebra $B$ can be concretely represented as the subset of points of Stone space (corresponding to homomorphisms $\phi: B \to 2$) such that $\phi(F) = 1$. (continued)

Comment: At this point, maybe we should continue in a chat room, although conceivably these comments would suffice, with a little effort, for you to piece it together...

Comment: Todd, thank you for the extra exposition. I am tempted by your chat room offer but I think at this point the best thing for me to do is to spend some time learning the fundamentals and studying the responses here. I might be more interested at a future date, if that is okay with you. I am working through Givant and Halmos (2009) "Introduction to Boolean Algebras" which is self-contained and leads up to stone duality. Thank you again for the extended discussion, I am fascinated by this stuff and the glimmer of understanding I've gotten so far is enticing.

Comment: Sure, that'd be fine. I don't know Givant-Halmos, but the late Paul Halmos was a gifted expositor and Givant was one of his PhD students; I'm confident you've latched onto an excellent reference and likely a careful study will be very rewarding. Stone duality is by now a pretty big area with lots of offshoots, but for the purposes of studying free Boolean algebras, it can be viewed as an elaboration on the method of truth tables. Good luck in your quest!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that claim in the post is wrong, and you are correct to object. What is true — and I was very surprised to learn this — is that in the free Boolean algebra on a countably infinite set of generators, *every* subset of the generators has a least upper bound.

This is not to say that the Boolean algebra is complete, since it is easy to see that it is not: the free Boolean algebra on a countable set of generators is countably infinite, since every element is represented by a term, but no countably infinite Boolean algebra is complete, since it must have an infinite antichain, and all subsets of an antichain must have distinct least upper bounds when they exist. So if it were complete, it would have to have size continuum.

In the free Boolean algebra on generators $p_0,\ p_1,\ldots$, the "disjointified" collection $p_0,\ p_1\wedge\neg p_0,\ p_2\wedge\neg(p_0\vee p_1),\ldots$ is an infinite (maximal) antichain. One can prove that a subset of this antichain has a least upper bound in the free algebra just in case it is finite or cofinite.

Nevertheless, to stress the point, every subset of the generating set itself does have a least upper bound.

**Theorem.** If $B$ is the free Boolean algebra on a set
of generators $Y$, then every subset of $Y$ has a least upper bound
in $B$. Furthermore, the infinite subsets of $Y$ all have least
upper bound $1$.

One can begin to see the latter claim intuitively, if you should merely try to imagine what would be the least upper bound of a infinite subset of $Y$ that, say, contains all the variables except some $p$. There is no natural candidate, other than $1$ itself; note that $\neg p$ is not an upper bound of the other variables, since variables are not disjoint in the free Boolean algebra.

**Proof.** Clearly, any finite subset $X\subset Y$ has a least
upper bound, which is simply the finite disjunction of the elements
of the set $\bigvee_{p\in X} p$.

Suppose now that $X\subset Y$ is infinite. (This argument was noticed also by user მამუკა ჯიბლაძე in the comments.) Clearly $1$ is an upper
bound of $X$; what we need to show is that there is no smaller
upper bound. Suppose that $u<1$ is an element of $B$. Using the
term algebra, we know that every element of $B$ is represented as a
term using finitely many variables of $Y$. Fix such a term, and let
$p$ be some element of $X$ not appearing in that term. Since $u<1$ and
$p$ does not appear in the term for $u$, I claim that there is a homomorphism
sending $u$ to $0$ and $p$ to $1$. To see this, we merely need to
settle the values of the variables appearing in the term for $u$ in
such a way that $u$ becomes $0$, and this is determined by settling the values of the variables appearing in that term, and we can independently send $p$
to $1$ by freeness. Since homomorphisms preserve order, it
cannot be that $p\leq u$. So we have shown that no element of $B$ other than $1$ is an upper bound of $X$, and so the least upper bound of $X$ is $1$.

An alternative argument was suggested in the comments by Andreas Blass: if $X\subset Y$ is infinite with upper bound $u$, let $p$ be variable of $X$ not used the term representing $u$. By freeness, there is an automorphism of the Boolean algebra sending $p$ to $\neg p$ and fixing all other variables and therefore also fixing $u$. Since $p\leq u$, it follows by applying the automorphism that also $(\neg p)\leq u$. Since $1=p\vee\neg p$, this means $u=1$. 
**QED**

Meanwhile, if instead of the free algebra one has the Boolean algebra generated by an infinite set of atoms, then something closer to the claim is true:

**Theorem.** If $B$ is the Boolean algebra generated by an infinite set of atoms $Y$, then the subsets of $Y$ with a least upper bound in $B$ are exactly the finite or co-finite subsets of $Y$.

**Proof.** It is not difficult to see that the Boolean algebra $B$ is isomorphic to the set of finite and co-finite subsets of $Y$, with the usual set-theoretic operations. If $X\subset Y$ is infinite and co-infinite, therefore, then clearly no finite or co-finite set can be a least upper bound of $X$.**QED**

Comment: This was the first example that I thought of and I even started to write an answer, but I don't think it works.  The trouble is in the next to last sentence, where you say that one of the generators, $q$, is disjoint from some other generators, those in $X$. In the free Boolean algebra on a set of generators, distinct generators are not disjoint. I think the argument can be repaired by using some disjoint things in place of the generators, for example $p_0\land p_1\land\dots\land p_{n-1}\land\neg p_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Ah, you are right! I'll think about this and edit.

Comment: This point seems to break the co-finite part of the argument also. I am now confused about it...

Comment: I believe any infinite set $X$ of generators has least upper bound $1$: take any $b\in B$. There is a generator $p\in X$ such that $b$ does not depend on $p$. Then if $b\ne1$, there is a homomorphism $B\to2$ sending $b$ to $0$ and $p$ to $1$, so one cannot have $p\leqslant b$.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion myself while I was doing some woodwork this afternoon. So every subset of the generators has a least upper bound!

Comment: I'll edit and post a revised argument later, unless you want to do it.

Comment: I have now edited with the revised argument. Every subset has a least upper bound!  This is very surprising.

Comment: Here's an alternative way to see that $1$ is the only upper bound for an infinite set $X$ of generators. Let $u$ be any upper bound for $X$ and let $p$ be an element of $X$ that doesn't occur in the term $u$. The algebra has an automorphism that sends $p$ to $\neg p$ and fixes all the other generators. So it fixes $u$, and since $p\leq u$, we also have $(\neg p)\leq u$. Therefore $1=p\lor(\neg p)\leq u$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Your argument is certainly "more" constructive than mine - I need ultrafilters and you only (some form of) excluded middle. I think in fact excluded middle can be avoided too but don't know how to do it...

Comment: I edited to include your nice argument, Andreas, as an alternative.

Comment: In fact I do not quite see how to express equationally that the generators are atoms. Does $a_i\land a_j=\bot$ suffice for that?

Comment: Yes, that suffices, since if those equations are true, then the $a_i$ will be atoms in the generated algebra. But in fact there is no need to express this equationally; in the theorem at the end, the situation is that we have a Boolean algebra that happens to have some atoms, and those atoms happen to generate the whole Boolean algebra.

Comment: Just a small comment: For the special case of the free boolean algebra on countably many generators, if you view it as the set of equivalence classes for propositional logic (= the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra for propositional logic), the fact that every subset of the generators has a lub is easy to see- it is just the disjunction if the set is finite, and the tautology if the set is infinite.

Comment: Can you briefly clarify the following? (infinite antichains) + (complete) => (size continuum). This is an argument I have seen a few times but I am still grappling with it. I do not see why the fact that distinct subsets have distinct lubs leads to size continuum. What about the fact that (every element in the antichain) <= 1?

Comment: @dwymark Is it "easy to see" that the LUB of an infinite set of generators in the Lindenbuam algebra is the tautology? I didn't see this without the arguments mentioned in my answer. Of course, no candidate LUB comes easily to mind, but to prove that there isn't one, it seems one must argue as in my answer.

Comment: @dwymark Concerning (infinite antichains) + (complete) implies (size at least continuum), this is easy. If A is an infinite antichain and every subset of A has a LUB, then the power set P(A) algebra embeds in the Boolean algebra, by mapping every subset of A to its LUB. This is injective, and in fact a Boolean embedding. Since P(A) has size at least continuum if A is infinite, the Boolean algebra is at least this large.

Comment: Thanks @Joel, I see why the continuum argument works now. As for whether it's "easy to see": you are right, there needs to be a proof, and I'm sure yours works. But on the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra view- to me it seems obvious that  (1) the tautology is an UB, and (2) no other element could possibly serve as an UB since this would require an infinitely long formula, which is disallowed by the syntax. (2) must hold because for a formula F to be an UB for a set of generators S, each generator $s\in S$ must show up at least once in F. Right? Or am I skirting over some details?

Comment: The Lindenbaum algebra and the term algebra are basically identical, so you can see how I argued with it. Since any term (formula) has only finitely many generators (variables) in it, there is some generator not appearing in it, and this is what causes problems, which you can see by considering the automorphisms I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Todd Trimble is precise enough, I just would like to complement it with some additional considerations.

Upper bounds of any subset of any Boolean algebra form a $\textit{normal filter}$, and lower bounds of any subset form a $\textit{normal ideal}$. Normal filters are in one-to-one correspondence with $\textit{regular closed}$ subsets of the Stone space of the algebra, and normal ideals with $\textit{regular open}$ subsets of the Stone space (so also both (normal filters) $\leftrightarrow$ (normal ideals) and (regular closeds) $\leftrightarrow$ (regular opens) are in one-to-one (order reversing) correspondences with each other).

Thus subsets without a lub are detected by $\textit{nonprincipal}$ normal filters which correspond to $\textit{nonclopen}$ regular closed sets, and subsets without a glb are detected by nonprincipal normal ideals which correspond to nonclopen regular open sets.

**Caveat** (and I made an actual mistake in my comment to the question here): given a set of clopens whose intersection is not (cl)open, it does not yet produce an example of a set without a glb in the algebra. For that, in addition, $\textit{interior of that intersection must not be closed}$. In other words, union of clopens contained in that intersection must not be closed.

An example of a regular open set in the Cantor space $C\subset\mathbb R$ is its intersection with some open interval $(a,b)$. This regular open is not clopen whenever either $a$ or $b$ is in $C\setminus\{\frac i{3^j}\mid i,j=0,1,2,...\}$.

In this realization of $C$, the variables $p_i$ correspond to the following clopens:
\begin{align*}
p_1&\mapsto C\cap[0,\frac13];\\
p_2&\mapsto C\cap([0,\frac19]\cup[\frac23,\frac79]);\\
p_3&\mapsto C\cap([0,\frac1{27}]\cup[\frac29,\frac7{27}]\cup[\frac23,\frac{19}{27}]\cup[\frac89,\frac{25}{27}]);\\
\cdots
\end{align*}
and the formulæ $\neg^{\varepsilon_1}p_1\land\cdots\land\neg^{\varepsilon_n}p_n$ capture all clopens of the form $C_{ij}:=C\cap[\frac i{3^j},\frac{i+1}{3^j}]$ with $j\leqslant n$. For example, $p_1\land p_2\mapsto C_{02}$, $p_1\land\neg p_2\mapsto C_{22}$, $\neg p_1\land p_2\mapsto C_{62}$, $\neg p_1\land\neg p_2\mapsto C_{82}$, ..., $p_1\land\cdots\land p_n\mapsto C_{0n}$, ..., $\neg p_1\land\cdots\land\neg p_n\mapsto C_{3^n-1,n}$, etc.

Thus given any nonclopen regular open $C\cap(a,b)$ as above, a set of formulæ without a lub in the free Boolean algebra corresponds to $\{C_{ij}\mid C_{ij}\subset(a,b), i,j=0,1,...\}$, i. e. to $\{C_{ij}\mid3^ja<i<3^jb-1\}$.

Todd's example is one such, chosen in a way to need as less mess as possible.

Of course there are lots of other sets without lubs. First, you may represent a nonclopen regular open as a union of clopens in many different ways. Second, most nonclopen regular opens are not of the form $C\cap(a,b)$; one can take $C\cap((a,b)\cup(a',b'))$, etc. - many (although by no means any) infinite unions of intervals also produce nonclopen regular opens of $C$.

(I hope I did not make another mistake somewhere :D )

Comment: Quick question: what exactly do you mean by "detectable by" in the third paragraph? Do you mean "correspond to"? Just making sure I understand your claim before I try to study your answer in more detail.

Comment: @dwymark I should be more precise. For a subset $S$ let $F^S$ be the set of all upper bounds of $S$, and let $I_S$ be the set of all lower bounds of $F^S$. Similarly, let $I^S$ be the set of all lower bounds of $S$ and let $F_S$ be the set of all upper bounds of $I^S$. Then $F^S$ and $F_S$ are normal filters, $I_S$ and $I^S$ are normal ideals, $S\subseteq I_S$, $S\subseteq F_S$, and $S$ has a lub iff $I_S$ is principal iff $F^S$ is principal, and $S$ has a glb iff $F_S$ is principal iff $I^S$ is principal..

Comment: It is just the [MacNeille completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93MacNeille_completion) that I am describing here, it works for arbitrary posets. When the poset is a Boolean algebra then Stone duality may be used to represent normal filters by regular closed sets of the Stone space, and normal ideals by regular open sets.

Comment: In more detail, every boolean algebra $B$ may be identified with the algebra of all clopens of a Stone space $X$; then every filter $\mathscr F$ of $B$ has form $\mathscr F_F=\{C\mid C\supseteq F\}$ for a unique closed subset $F$ of $X$, and every ideal $\mathscr I$ of $B$ has form $\mathscr I_U=\{C\mid C\subseteq U\}$ for a unique open subset $U$ of $X$. Moreover $\mathscr F_F$ is normal iff $F$ is regular closed and $\mathscr I_U$ is normal iff $U$ is regular open.

Comment: Thank you, this is much more clear. I'll need some time to study it all before I can ask any more questions, if any come up.